# VB-Catching first 4 characters in textbox

Tags: vb.net, string, winforms

I am currently working on a really basic scripting langauge (called EngineScript) that gets the first 4 letters of a textbox's content (in a Windows Form project) and compares it to a in-program list of keywords and then uses the remaining characters to form an argument to the keywords...
I was wondering weather you had some code ideas on how to go about placing the first 4 letters in one variable and then the remaining characters into another.
My langauge will be single command.. i.e you will only be able to run one command per program.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[String.Substring()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx) should work:

```
Dim first4Chars = TextBox1.Text.Substring(0, 4)
Dim restOfChars = TextBox1.Text.Substring(4)
```

Comment: @VladimarChudnofski You should accept this answer if it answered your question. :)

Answer (score 1):

I will show you a good hint on how to get the first four letters, and see what you can put together with that. VB was a pain in my neck!! I struggled through it, and realized that is the only way to learn.. =)

```
dim substring as string

substringA = Left$("Entered String", 4)

strSubstrA = "Ente"

substringB = Left$("What about a space?", 6)

strSubstrB = "What a"
```

Answer (score 1):

Carefull with [Substring()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx) function as it assumes that the textbox length is greater or equal than the second parameter. So if in your input someone puts less than 4 characters it will blow.

You should this to be safe:

```
Dim txt1 as String = Textbox1.Text
Dim first4Chars = If(txt1.Length > 4, txt1.Substring(0, 4), txt1.SubString(0,text.Length))
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
Dim l4 as string, rest as string
l4 = LEFT(TextBox1.Text, 4)
rest = MID(TextBox1.Text, 5, LEN(TextBox1.Text))
```

Comment: Sorry...I should mention that I use VS2012...The 'LEFT()' code is supposedly only for integers/numbers in VB2012...Do you know any other ways

Comment: @VladimarChudnofski No, that is not true.  The LEFT function still works the same as it has for the last 30 years.  Here's the VB2012 doc: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.left.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not too clear ..

But you can try this

```
dim sVar as string = mid(TextBox1.text,1,4)
```